# Как подключиться к сайтам по очереди и вывести результат

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Хотел реализовать программу которая проверяет сайты по списку и выводит состояние доступен сайт или нет. Но столкнулся с проблемой что подключается только к последнему сайту из списка и всем сайтам присваивает состояние последнего

```
import socket

hosts = ['ya.ru', 'vk.com', 'fb.com']
port = 80

s = socket.socket()
s.settimeout(1)

try:
    for host in hosts:
        print(host)
    s.connect((host, port))

except socket.error:
    for host in hosts:
        print('сайт ' + host + ' не доступен!')
else:
    for host in hosts:
        print('сайт ' + host + ' доступен')
```

Comment: `подключается только к последнему сайту из списка` – а это потому, что строке `s.connect(...)` не хватает отступа, она выполняется не в цикле `for` а сразу после него.

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос так:

```
import socket

hosts = ['ya.ru', 'vk.com', 'fb.com']
port = 80

for host in hosts:
    s = socket.socket()
    s.settimeout(1)
    try:
        s.connect((host, port))
    except socket.error:
        print('сайт ' + host + ' не доступен!')
    else:
        print('сайт ' + host + ' доступен')
```

Если неправильно или есть какие замечания просьба написать

Answer (score 1):

```
import socket

hosts = ['ya.ru', 'vk.com', 'fb.com']
port = 80


def knock(host, port):
    skt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        skt.connect((host, port))
        skt.shutdown(2)
        return True
    except socket.error:
        return False


try:
    for host in hosts:
        if knock(host,port):
            print('сайт ' + host + ' доступен')
        else:
            print('сайт ' + host + ' не доступен!')

except socket.error:
        print("error")
```

Comment: А зачем ловить снаружи исключение `socket.error`, если в методе `knock` оно уже ловится, а `print` его никогда не выбросит? В этом коде последние две строки никогда не выполнятся.

Comment: ну я же его код менял) на автомате принт докинул

Comment: Спасибо, буду работать над собой и учиться писать правильно

Answer (score 1):

Вы поменяли местами try-except и перебор в цикле. Попытку нужно делать отдельно для каждого элемента в перебираемом списке.

Ваш код человеческим языком:

```
попробовать:
    зайти на все сайты по очереди

если в процессе хоть раз была ошибка:
    напечатать про каждый сайт, что он недоступен

если всё хорошо:
    напечатать про каждый сайт, что он доступен
```

А нужно так:

```
с каждым сайтом из списка:

    попробовать: 
        зайти на сайт

    если не получилось:
        напечатать, что сайт недоступен

    если получилось:
        напечатать, что сайт доступен
```

Comment: Спасибо, мне нужно больше работать над собой